# T-SQL equivalent of To_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I have a function in oracle and I am trying to re-write the same in sql server. I tried to rewrite it using cast, but didn't work. I am stuck. Can someone suggest a workaround. Here's the oracle code and I have to convert to sql server:

```
FUNCTION IsNumeric (sRESPONSE_STRING IN FY_ST_ANSWER_DETAIL.RESPONSE_STRING%TYPE Default NULL)
    RETURN BOOLEAN
    IS
    test_value NUMERIC;
    BEGIN
         test_value := To_Number(Replace(Replace(sRESPONSE_STRING,','),'$'));
         RETURN (true);

            EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN (false);
        END;
```

Thanks..

Here's what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [HSIP].[Isnumeric] 
(
    @sResponse_string varchar(250)

)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE testvalue= cast((@sresponse_string) as varchar[250]);


return @testvalue;
END
```

Comment: Please share what you tried, and what error you got.

Comment: Please show the code you tried with CAST, and why it didn't work.   What error, or incorrect result did you get.   Also you're more likely to get helped if you ask your question in a way that a SQL Server expert doesn't also have to be an Oracle expert in order to answer it.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION [HSIP].[Isnumeric] 
(
 @sResponse_string varchar(250)

)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
BEGIN
 -- Declare the return variable here
 DECLARE testvalue= cast((@sresponse_string) as varchar[250]);


return @testvalue;
END

Comment: sorry, will post my code under my original post. Sorry, I am new to sql server. So, please bear with me. Thanks

Comment: t-sql has an `isnumeric` function [built in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx). I'm not sure if that's exactly what you are you looking for, but it may be a good start.

Comment: `Replace()` also exists, so you could do a `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(field1, ',',''),'$','') THEN 'Its Numeric!' ELSE 'Its Not Numeric :(' END as Is_the_Field_Numeric` No need for a UDF replacement.

Comment: @JNevill. Will try your approach.

Comment: Read the documentation of the ISNUMERIC function for SQL Server.   You don't need to do the same REPLACE() functions, because characters like comma and dot are already considered "numeric" for this purpose.   Can't remember if dollar sign is numeric or not.

Comment: I tried this:    CREATE FUNCTION [HSIP].[Isnumeric] 
(
 @sResponse_string varchar(250)

)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
BEGIN

RETURN
CASE

WHEN @sResponse_string= ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(@sResponse_string, ',',''),'$','')) THEN 1
ELSE  0



END
GO

Comment: it doesn't point to any error but i get incorrect syntax near end

Comment: SQL Server does not have a BOOLEAN datatype. And ISNUMERIC returns way too many false positives to be valid most of the time. It is a function that returns true if the value is able to be converted to any datatype that is roughly numeric in nature. It returns true for arbitrary values like '$.' and '1e4' and a whole litany of other bizarre values. Check out this article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Answer (score 4):

JT has a correct answer. Here is how to apply it in your code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [HSIP].[Isnumeric]  (@InputVar varchar(250))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnVal BIT

    IF ISNUMERIC(@InputVar) = 1
       SET @returnVal = 1 --true
    ELSE
       SET @returnVal = 0 --false

RETURN @returnVal
END
```

I would suggest you read up on ISNUMERIC though. Depending on where you are at and what you want to classify as a numeral, there are things to take into consideration.

Most of the common formats will work--but you may have a format that is different. All of these below would classify as NUMERIC, but ISNUMERIC can return things that you wouldn't expect to be NUMERIC.

```
select isnumeric('12.556')     --returns true / 1
select isnumeric('12,556')     --returns true / 1
select isnumeric('12,556.66')  --returns true / 1
select isnumeric('$12,556.66') --returns true / 1
select isnumeric('1e56')       --returns true / 1
```

Alternatively, if you use SQL 2012 or later, you can use TRY_CONVERT an potentially achieve more accurate results.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [HSIP].[Isnumeric]  (@InputVar varchar(250))
    RETURNS BIT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @returnVal BIT

        IF TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,@InputVar) IS NOT NULL
           SET @returnVal = 1 --true
        ELSE
           SET @returnVal = 0 --false

    RETURN @returnVal
    END
```

As you will notice... commas are handled differently here, so are money signs.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,'12556')      --returns true  / 12556
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,'12.556')     --returns true  / 13
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,'12,556')     --returns false / NULL
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,'12,556.66')  --returns false / NULL
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,'$12,556.66') --returns false / NULL
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,'1e56')       --returns false / NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @scsimon. Your solution works perfectly fine for my scenario. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3147594 be sure to check out the latest edit with emphasis on TRY_CONVERT as well to get more accurate, or at least more predictable results.

Comment: Nice job on that answer.

Comment: Thanks @J.T.  I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

There is no exception handling in SQL Server user defined functions. However, there is a built in function called ISNUMERIC.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC( 'FOO' ), ISNUMERIC( 1 )
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC is not solid enough for what the OP is trying to do. select isnumeric('1e4')

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function ISNUMERIC https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186272.aspx

Comment: ISNUMERIC is not solid enough for what the OP is trying to do. select isnumeric('1e4')

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. Simon's response helped.

```
LTER FUNCTION [hsip].[Isnumeric]  

(@sResponse_string varchar(250))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnVal BIT

    IF ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(@sResponse_string, ',',''),'$','')) = 1
       SET @returnVal = 1 --true
    ELSE
       SET @returnVal = 0 --false

RETURN @returnVal
END
```

Comment: This is not really very good. Consider these values. 1e4, 5d9. There are many more that will convince the built in ISNUMERIC that the value is numeric when it isn't.

Comment: also ISNUMERIC() takes into account $ and , as numeric so no need to replace them which means all the function really does is return ISNUMERIC()